# Why is there no space between name of these columns?

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

I'm trying to edit the layout of this [html](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1k_35bZ59G1hwxAXbeEjir1paZIiksFwe?usp=sharing). In the attached link, I include both `html` and `css` files. In the click-to-expand content `Full verb table`, there are some columns for which there is no space between their names.

[image]

and

[image]

I look at their source code and see no difference with other columns for which there is a suitable space between their names.

```
<div class="type"><h3>Past Participle</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimé</li></ul></div>

<div class="type"><h3>Gerund</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimant</li></ul></div>

<div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperative</h3><ul><li class="infl">aime (tu)</li><li class="infl">aimons (nous)</li><li class="infl">aimez (vous)</li></ul></div>
```

My questions:

1. Could you please explain why such miss-arrangement occurs?
2. I've tried to edit the CSS so that there is no indentation before each line, but to no avail. Could you please help me edit the CSS to achieve my goal?

   .type .infl {
   display: block;
   padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
   }

   .conjugation .infl {
   display: block;
   padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
   }

   .conjugation .infl .vb {
   font-weight: 600;
   }

Thank you so much for your help!

---

Update: I include the full content of the html and CSS.

html:

```
aimer
<link href="Collins.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="collins.js"></script>
<div class="cB cB-def dictionary biling" data-num-block="" data-title-block="" data-type-block="aimer" id="aimer__1"><div class="cB-h"><div class="title_container"><div class="title_frequency_container"><div class="word-frequency-container res_hos frenquency-title"><div class="label">Word Frequency</div><span class="word-frequency-img" data-band="4" data-word="aimer" title="Very Common. aimer is one of the 4000 most commonly used words in the Collins dictionary"><span class="level level1 roundRed"></span><span class="level level2 roundRed"></span><span class="level level3 roundRed"></span><span class="level level4 roundRed"></span><span class="level level5"></span></span></div></div><h2 class="h2_entry"><span class="orth">aimer</span></h2></div></div><div class="mini_h2"><span class="form"><span class="punctuation"> [</span><span class="pron type-">eme<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound"><a href="sound://FR-W0050640.mp3"><img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/></a><a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" data-lang="en_GB" data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0050640.mp3" title="Pronunciation for "></a></span></span><span class="punctuation">]</span></span></div><div class="content definitions dictionary biling"><div class="hom"><span class="gramGrp"><span class="xr"> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a></span><span class="hi rend-sc pos">transitive verb</span></span><html><body><div class="fullverbtable"><link href="collins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><script src="collins.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div class="columns2"><div class="type"><h3>Infinitive</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimer</li></ul></div><div class="type"><h3>Past Participle</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimé</li></ul></div><div class="type"><h3>Gerund</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimant</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperative</h3><ul><li class="infl">aime (tu)</li><li class="infl">aimons (nous)</li><li class="infl">aimez (vous)</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aime</li><li class="infl">tu aimes</li><li class="infl">il/elle aime</li><li class="infl">nous aimons</li><li class="infl">vous aimez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aiment</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'ai aimé</li><li class="infl">tu as aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle a aimé</li><li class="infl">nous avons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous avez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles ont aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimais</li><li class="infl">tu aimais</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimait</li><li class="infl">nous aimions</li><li class="infl">vous aimiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimaient</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Future</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimerai</li><li class="infl">tu aimeras</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimera</li><li class="infl">nous aimerons</li><li class="infl">vous aimerez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimeront</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Conditional</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimerais</li><li class="infl">tu aimerais</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimerait</li><li class="infl">nous aimerions</li><li class="infl">vous aimeriez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimeraient</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Past Historic</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimai</li><li class="infl">tu aimas</li><li class="infl">il/elle aima</li><li class="infl">nous aimâmes</li><li class="infl">vous aimâtes</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimèrent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Pluperfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'avais aimé</li><li class="infl">tu avais aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle avait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous avions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous aviez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles avaient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Future Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aurai aimé</li><li class="infl">tu auras aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle aura aimé</li><li class="infl">nous aurons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous aurez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles auront aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Past Anterior</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'eus aimé</li><li class="infl">tu eus aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle eut aimé</li><li class="infl">nous eûmes aimé</li><li class="infl">vous eûtes aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles eurent aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Conditional Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aurais aimé</li><li class="infl">tu aurais aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle aurait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous aurions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous auriez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles auraient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aime</li><li class="infl">tu aimes</li><li class="infl">il/elle aime</li><li class="infl">nous aimions</li><li class="infl">vous aimiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aiment</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimasse</li><li class="infl">tu aimasses</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimât</li><li class="infl">nous aimassions</li><li class="infl">vous aimassiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimassent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Perfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aie aimé</li><li class="infl">tu aies aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle ait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous ayons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous ayez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Pluperfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'eusse aimé</li><li class="infl">tu eusses aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle eût aimé</li><li class="infl">nous eussions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous eussiez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles eussent aimé</li></ul></div></div></div></body></html><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">1. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>d’amour<span class="punctuation">)</span></span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to love</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Elle aime ses enfants.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">She loves her children.</span></div></div><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">2. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>d’amitié, par affection<span class="punctuation">)</span></span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like</span><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">bien aimer qn</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like sb</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime bien Paul, on peut vraiment compter sur lui.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I really like Paul, he’s so reliable.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Je n’aime pas beaucoup Marie.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I don’t like Marie very much.</span></div></div> </div><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">3. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>par goût<span class="gramGrp colloc"><span class="punctuation">) </span><span class="punctuation">[</span>aliment, divertissement, auteur<span class="punctuation">]</span></span></span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Tu aimes le chocolat ?</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">Do you like chocolate?</span></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">bien aimer qch</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like sth</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime bien jouer au tennis.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I like playing tennis.</span></div></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">aimer faire qch</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like doing sth</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime assez aller au cinéma.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I quite like going to the cinema.</span></div></div> <div class="mpuslot_b-container"> </div> </div><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">4. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>préférence<span class="punctuation">)</span></span><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">aimer mieux qn que qn</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to prefer sb to sb</span></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">aimer mieux qch que qch</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to prefer sth to sth</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime mieux Paul.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I prefer Paul.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime mieux Paul que Pierre.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I prefer Paul to Pierre.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Il aime mieux faire la cuisine qu’aller au restaurant.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">He’d rather cook than go to a restaurant.</span></div></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">j’aime mieux vous dire que</span><span class="form type-phr"><span class="punctuation">, </span><span class="orth">j’aime autant vous dire que</span></span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I may as well tell you that</span></div> </div><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">5. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>conditionnel : souhait<span class="punctuation">)</span></span><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">j’aimerais ...</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I would like ...</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais aller en Écosse.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d like to go to Scotland.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Aimeriez-vous que je vous accompagne ?</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">Would you like me to come with you?</span></div></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">j’aimerais bien ...</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I would like ...</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais bien m’en aller.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d like to go.</span></div></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">j’aimerais mieux faire ...</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d rather do ...</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais mieux ne pas y aller.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d rather not go.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais mieux y aller maintenant.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d rather go now.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais autant y aller maintenant.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d rather go now.</span></div></div> <div class="mpuslot_b-container"> </div> </div></div><span class="xr"> <span class="lbl italics">see also</span><a class="ref" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/s-aimer" title="Translation of s’aimer">s’aimer</a></span><div class="cB-w" id="id_idm140081449731952"><h2 class="entry_title">Verb conjugations for aimer</h2><div class="short_verb_table"><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aime</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimes</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aime</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aiment</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Future</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimerai</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimeras</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimera</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimerons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimerez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimeront</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Imperfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimait</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimions</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimiez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimaient</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present Perfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">ai aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> as aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> a aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> avons aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> avez aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> ont aimé</span></span></span></div> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a></div></div></div><div class="cB cB-e dcCorpEx" data-type-block="Example sentences"><div class="cB-h"><h2 class="entry_title">Examples of 'aimer' in a sentence</h2></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>A l'inverse, on peut aimer cette hétérogénéité - l'aimer d'autant plus que son auteur est inconnu. </blockquote><cite><span class="title">Le Monde</span> <span class="year">(2002)</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>C'est un crève-coeur que de ne pouvoir aimer tous les hommes. </blockquote><cite><span class="author">Desproges, Pierre</span> <span class="title">Chroniques de la haine ordinaire</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Ce genre de garçons lui faisait aimer son frère encore davantage. </blockquote><cite><span class="author">Dangerfield, Yves &amp; Girod, Francis</span> <span class="title">L'enfance de l'art</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Elle doit être aussi en action pour les faire vivre, les faire partager, les faire aimer », a conclu Jacques Chirac. </blockquote><cite><span class="title">Le Nouvel Observateur</span> <span class="year">(2003)</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Mais, c'est exact, c'est parce qu'ils sont au chômage qu'ils peuvent se rencontrer, s'aimer. </blockquote><cite><span class="title">Le Monde</span> <span class="year">(2000)</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Qu'il m'étouffait, que je ne comprenais pas comment j'avais pu l'aimer et que je ne voulais plus le revoir. </blockquote><cite><span class="title">Marie Claire</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Un homme et une femme, jeunes, pas mariés ; ils se retrouvent souvent sur la terrasse pour s'aimer. </blockquote><cite><span class="author">Ben Jelloun, Tahar</span> <span class="title">La nuit sacrée</span> </cite></div><div class="mpuslot_b-container"> <div class="am-default contentslot" id="ad_contentslot_3"></div></div> </div>
</>
```

and CSS:

```
.share-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.type h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E52B50;
}

.columns2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.conjugation h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #9966CC;
}

.conjugation .title {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.short_verb_table {
  display: flex;
}

.type .infl {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.conjugation .infl {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.conjugation .infl .vb {
  font-weight: 600;
}

a.link-right.verbtable {
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: #e5ebf3;
}

.cB-w .link-right.verbtable {
  display: none;
}

.wnv.entry_title {
  display: none;
}

.cB.cB-hook {
  display: none;
}

.content.definitions.dictionary.biling > .xr {
  display: none;
}

.hi.rend-sc.pos {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0069B4;
}

.pos {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0069B4;
}

.cit.type-translation.quote {
  color: #A50021;
}

.lbl.type-misc {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gramGrp.colloc {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.share-button {
  display: none;
}

.popup-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.titleExType {
  display: none;
}

.title_frequency_container {
  float: right;
  height: 0;
}
.word-frequency-img {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.word-frequency-img,
.frenquency-title .label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.word-frequency-container .level {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2928e;
}
.word-frequency-container .level.roundRed {
  background-color: #c12d30;
}
.word-frequency-container .level1 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level2 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level3 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level4 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level5 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
.word-frequency-container .round {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.example-info {
  display: none;
}

.h2_entry {

  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.copyright {
  display: none;
}

div.sense {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.cB.cB-e .entry_title {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.cB.cB-e::before {
  content: "Example sentences";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.titleExType {
  font-weight: 600;
}


.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx::before {
  content: "Example sentences";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: black solid;
}

.cB.cB-e {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: black solid;
}

.cit.type-example.cit {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.cit.type-example.cit .quote {
  font-style: italic;
}

.credits.popup-button .author {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.credits.popup-button .title {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
}

.mpuslot_b-container {
  display: none;
}

.fullverbtable {
  display: none;
}

.cB-h .entry_title .h2_entry {
  display: none;
}

a.link-right.verbtable::before {
  /* content: attr(data-text); */
  font-weight: 600;
}

.fullverbtable h1 {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fullverbtable h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fullverbtable ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conjugation h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conjugation ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* a.audio_play_button::before {
    pointer-events: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    content: "1";
} */

.example_box {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.example_box blockquote {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.example_box .author {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.example_box .title {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
}

img.imageImg {
  height: 300px;
}

img.soundpng {
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 16px;
}

.gramGrp.pos {
  color: #0069B4;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you could attach your css and html code

Comment: Why do you use HTML lists when the easiest way is to use a table?

Comment: @Riddhijain I add both html and css in the link right at the beginning.

Comment: @xKobalt This is because the html is saved from the link crawled from [website](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer).

Comment: Mh... ok... the only problem I have now is I can't open the file attached, could you please provide that plain here?

Comment: @xKobalt Because the file contains many lines, I think it's not reading-friendly to post it here. I make a [new folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1k_35bZ59G1hwxAXbeEjir1paZIiksFwe?usp=sharing). Please download it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D Do you know why my code for CSS in question 2 is not well-formatted? It's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer does not produce a minimal reproducible sample, but this provides a solution for the OP needings.

**Code:**

```js
function expandfullverbtable() {
  var attr1 = document
    .getElementsByClassName("fullverbtable")[0]
    .getAttribute("style");
  if (attr1 == null || attr1 == "display:none") {
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("fullverbtable")[0]
      .setAttribute("style", "display:block");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("cB-w")[0]
      .setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("verbtable")[0]
      .setAttribute("data-text", "- ");
  }

  if (attr1 == "display:block") {
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("cB-w")[0]
      .setAttribute("style", "display:block");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("fullverbtable")[0]
      .setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("verbtable")[0]
      .setAttribute("data-text", "+ ");
  }
}
```

```css
/*ADDED CSS*/

div.type, div.conjugation {
  min-width: 240px;
}

ul {
    padding-inline-start: 5px;
}

/*END ADDED CSS*/

.share-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.type h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E52B50;
}

.columns2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.type .infl {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.conjugation h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #9966CC;
}

.short_verb_table {
  display: flex;

}

.conjugation .infl {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.conjugation .title {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.conjugation .infl .vb {
  font-weight: 600;
}

a.link-right.verbtable {
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: #e5ebf3;
}

.cB-w .link-right.verbtable {
  display: none;
}

.wnv.entry_title {
  display: none;
}

.cB.cB-hook {
  display: none;
}

.content.definitions.dictionary.biling > .xr {
  display: none;
}

.hi.rend-sc.pos {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0069B4;
}

.pos {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0069B4;
}

.cit.type-translation.quote {
  color: #A50021;
}

.lbl.type-misc {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gramGrp.colloc {
  color: #008000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.share-button {
  display: none;
}

.popup-overlay {
  display: none;
}

.titleExType {
  display: none;
}

.title_frequency_container {
  float: right;
  height: 0;
}
.word-frequency-img {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.word-frequency-img,
.frenquency-title .label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.word-frequency-container .level {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2928e;
}
.word-frequency-container .level.roundRed {
  background-color: #c12d30;
}
.word-frequency-container .level1 {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level2 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level3 {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level4 {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
}
.word-frequency-container .level5 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
.word-frequency-container .round {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.example-info {
  display: none;
}

.h2_entry {

  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.copyright {
  display: none;
}

div.sense {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.cB.cB-e .entry_title {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.cB.cB-e::before {
  content: "Example sentences";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.titleExType {
  font-weight: 600;
}


.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx::before {
  content: "Example sentences";
  font-weight: 600;
}

.cB.cB-e.dcCorpEx {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: black solid;
}

.cB.cB-e {
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  border: black solid;
}

.cit.type-example.cit {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.cit.type-example.cit .quote {
  font-style: italic;
}

.credits.popup-button .author {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.credits.popup-button .title {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
}

.mpuslot_b-container {
  display: none;
}

.fullverbtable {
  display: none;
}

.cB-h .entry_title .h2_entry {
  display: none;
}

a.link-right.verbtable::before {
  /* content: attr(data-text); */
  font-weight: 600;
}

.fullverbtable h1 {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fullverbtable h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.fullverbtable ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conjugation h3 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.conjugation ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* a.audio_play_button::before {
    pointer-events: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    content: "1";
} */

.example_box {
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.example_box blockquote {
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
.example_box .author {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
.example_box .title {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-style: italic;
}

img.imageImg {
  height: 300px;
}

img.soundpng {
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 16px;
}

.gramGrp.pos {
  color: #0069B4;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
aimer
<link href="Collins_test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="collins.js"></script>
<div class="cB cB-def dictionary biling" data-num-block="" data-title-block="" data-type-block="aimer" id="aimer__1"><div class="cB-h"><div class="title_container"><div class="title_frequency_container"><div class="word-frequency-container res_hos frenquency-title"><div class="label">Word Frequency</div><span class="word-frequency-img" data-band="4" data-word="aimer" title="Very Common. aimer is one of the 4000 most commonly used words in the Collins dictionary"><span class="level level1 roundRed"></span><span class="level level2 roundRed"></span><span class="level level3 roundRed"></span><span class="level level4 roundRed"></span><span class="level level5"></span></span></div></div><h2 class="h2_entry"><span class="orth">aimer</span></h2></div></div><div class="mini_h2"><span class="form"><span class="punctuation"> [</span><span class="pron type-">eme<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound"><a href="sound://FR-W0050640.mp3"><img class="soundpng" src="file://sound.png"/></a><a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" data-lang="en_GB" data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0050640.mp3" title="Pronunciation for "></a></span></span><span class="punctuation">]</span></span></div><div class="content definitions dictionary biling"><div class="hom"><span class="gramGrp"><span class="xr"> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a></span><span class="hi rend-sc pos">transitive verb</span></span><html><body><div class="fullverbtable"><link href="collins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><script src="collins.js" type="text/javascript"></script><div class="columns2"><div class="type"><h3>Infinitive</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimer</li></ul></div><div class="type"><h3>Past Participle</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimé</li></ul></div><div class="type"><h3>Gerund</h3><ul><li class="infl">aimant</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperative</h3><ul><li class="infl">aime (tu)</li><li class="infl">aimons (nous)</li><li class="infl">aimez (vous)</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aime</li><li class="infl">tu aimes</li><li class="infl">il/elle aime</li><li class="infl">nous aimons</li><li class="infl">vous aimez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aiment</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'ai aimé</li><li class="infl">tu as aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle a aimé</li><li class="infl">nous avons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous avez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles ont aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimais</li><li class="infl">tu aimais</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimait</li><li class="infl">nous aimions</li><li class="infl">vous aimiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimaient</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Future</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimerai</li><li class="infl">tu aimeras</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimera</li><li class="infl">nous aimerons</li><li class="infl">vous aimerez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimeront</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Conditional</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimerais</li><li class="infl">tu aimerais</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimerait</li><li class="infl">nous aimerions</li><li class="infl">vous aimeriez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimeraient</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Past Historic</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimai</li><li class="infl">tu aimas</li><li class="infl">il/elle aima</li><li class="infl">nous aimâmes</li><li class="infl">vous aimâtes</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimèrent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Pluperfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'avais aimé</li><li class="infl">tu avais aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle avait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous avions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous aviez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles avaient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Future Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aurai aimé</li><li class="infl">tu auras aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle aura aimé</li><li class="infl">nous aurons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous aurez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles auront aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Past Anterior</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'eus aimé</li><li class="infl">tu eus aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle eut aimé</li><li class="infl">nous eûmes aimé</li><li class="infl">vous eûtes aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles eurent aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Conditional Perfect</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aurais aimé</li><li class="infl">tu aurais aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle aurait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous aurions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous auriez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles auraient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aime</li><li class="infl">tu aimes</li><li class="infl">il/elle aime</li><li class="infl">nous aimions</li><li class="infl">vous aimiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aiment</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Imperfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aimasse</li><li class="infl">tu aimasses</li><li class="infl">il/elle aimât</li><li class="infl">nous aimassions</li><li class="infl">vous aimassiez</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aimassent</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Present Perfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'aie aimé</li><li class="infl">tu aies aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle ait aimé</li><li class="infl">nous ayons aimé</li><li class="infl">vous ayez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles aient aimé</li></ul></div><div class="conjugation"><h3>Pluperfect Subjunctive</h3><ul><li class="infl">j'eusse aimé</li><li class="infl">tu eusses aimé</li><li class="infl">il/elle eût aimé</li><li class="infl">nous eussions aimé</li><li class="infl">vous eussiez aimé</li><li class="infl">ils/elles eussent aimé</li></ul></div></div></div></body></html><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">1. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>d’amour<span class="punctuation">)</span></span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to love</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Elle aime ses enfants.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">She loves her children.</span></div></div><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">2. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>d’amitié, par affection<span class="punctuation">)</span></span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like</span><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">bien aimer qn</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like sb</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime bien Paul, on peut vraiment compter sur lui.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I really like Paul, he’s so reliable.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Je n’aime pas beaucoup Marie.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I don’t like Marie very much.</span></div></div> </div><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">3. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>par goût<span class="gramGrp colloc"><span class="punctuation">) </span><span class="punctuation">[</span>aliment, divertissement, auteur<span class="punctuation">]</span></span></span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Tu aimes le chocolat ?</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">Do you like chocolate?</span></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">bien aimer qch</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like sth</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime bien jouer au tennis.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I like playing tennis.</span></div></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">aimer faire qch</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to like doing sth</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime assez aller au cinéma.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I quite like going to the cinema.</span></div></div> <div class="mpuslot_b-container"> </div> </div><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">4. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>préférence<span class="punctuation">)</span></span><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">aimer mieux qn que qn</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to prefer sb to sb</span></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">aimer mieux qch que qch</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">to prefer sth to sth</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime mieux Paul.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I prefer Paul.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aime mieux Paul que Pierre.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I prefer Paul to Pierre.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Il aime mieux faire la cuisine qu’aller au restaurant.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">He’d rather cook than go to a restaurant.</span></div></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">j’aime mieux vous dire que</span><span class="form type-phr"><span class="punctuation">, </span><span class="orth">j’aime autant vous dire que</span></span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I may as well tell you that</span></div> </div><div class="sense"><span class="sensenum bluebold">5. </span> <span class="lbl type-misc"><span class="punctuation">(</span>conditionnel : souhait<span class="punctuation">)</span></span><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">j’aimerais ...</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I would like ...</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais aller en Écosse.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d like to go to Scotland.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">Aimeriez-vous que je vous accompagne ?</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">Would you like me to come with you?</span></div></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">j’aimerais bien ...</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I would like ...</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais bien m’en aller.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d like to go.</span></div></div><div class="re type-phr"><span class="form type-phr orth">j’aimerais mieux faire ...</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d rather do ...</span><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais mieux ne pas y aller.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d rather not go.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais mieux y aller maintenant.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d rather go now.</span></div><div class="cit type-example"><span class="quote">J’aimerais autant y aller maintenant.</span> <span class="cit type-translation quote">I’d rather go now.</span></div></div> <div class="mpuslot_b-container"> </div> </div></div><span class="xr"> <span class="lbl italics">see also</span><a class="ref" href="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/s-aimer" title="Translation of s’aimer">s’aimer</a></span><div class="cB-w" id="id_idm140081449731952"><h2 class="entry_title">Verb conjugations for aimer</h2><div class="short_verb_table"><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aime</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimes</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aime</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aiment</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Future</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimerai</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimeras</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimera</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimerons</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimerez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimeront</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Imperfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">aimais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> aimais</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> aimait</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> aimions</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> aimiez</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> aimaient</span></span></span><span class="conjugation"><span class="title">Present Perfect</span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">j'</span><span class="vb">ai aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">tu</span><span class="vb"> as aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">il/elle</span><span class="vb"> a aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">nous</span><span class="vb"> avons aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">vous</span><span class="vb"> avez aimé</span></span><span class="infl"><span class="pn">ils/elles</span><span class="vb"> ont aimé</span></span></span></div> <a class="link-right verbtable" data-text="+" old_onclick="expandfullverbtable();" onclick="expandfullverbtable();">Full verb table</a></div></div></div><div class="cB cB-e dcCorpEx" data-type-block="Example sentences"><div class="cB-h"><h2 class="entry_title">Examples of 'aimer' in a sentence</h2></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>A l'inverse, on peut aimer cette hétérogénéité - l'aimer d'autant plus que son auteur est inconnu. </blockquote><cite><span class="title">Le Monde</span> <span class="year">(2002)</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>C'est un crève-coeur que de ne pouvoir aimer tous les hommes. </blockquote><cite><span class="author">Desproges, Pierre</span> <span class="title">Chroniques de la haine ordinaire</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Ce genre de garçons lui faisait aimer son frère encore davantage. </blockquote><cite><span class="author">Dangerfield, Yves &amp; Girod, Francis</span> <span class="title">L'enfance de l'art</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Elle doit être aussi en action pour les faire vivre, les faire partager, les faire aimer », a conclu Jacques Chirac. </blockquote><cite><span class="title">Le Nouvel Observateur</span> <span class="year">(2003)</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Mais, c'est exact, c'est parce qu'ils sont au chômage qu'ils peuvent se rencontrer, s'aimer. </blockquote><cite><span class="title">Le Monde</span> <span class="year">(2000)</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Qu'il m'étouffait, que je ne comprenais pas comment j'avais pu l'aimer et que je ne voulais plus le revoir. </blockquote><cite><span class="title">Marie Claire</span> </cite></div><div class="example_box"><blockquote>Un homme et une femme, jeunes, pas mariés ; ils se retrouvent souvent sur la terrasse pour s'aimer. </blockquote><cite><span class="author">Ben Jelloun, Tahar</span> <span class="title">La nuit sacrée</span> </cite></div><div class="mpuslot_b-container"> <div class="am-default contentslot" id="ad_contentslot_3"></div></div> </div>
</>
```

**What I changed?** I just put the following CSS:

```
div.type, div.conjugation {
  min-width: 240px;
}

ul {
    padding-inline-start: 5px;
}
```

**Advice:** This code works better on fullscreen size and is not optimized!

Comment: May I ask why the text in the first 13 columns are left-oriented toward to column names? https://imgur.com/GQEPIMu.

Comment: Try now, I just remove `h3 { text-align: center }` and added `ul { padding-inline-start: 5px; }`, the last one is an override of the CSS default provided `<ul>` element